# How get string in a list with a regex passed in variable python

Tags: python, regex, list, variables, split

I need your help because i want to get a str in a list with regex with a variable in the regex.

```
 my_list = ['Lille, 90 rue d’Arras', 'Lille, 76 impasse Georges Pompidou',
'Lyon, 2 allée des fleurs', 'Toulouse, 90 rue Voltaire']

my_variable = "Lille"
regex = re.compile(r"\b(?=w)" + re.escape(my_variable) + r"\b(?!\w)")
adresse = [n.sub(', ', x).strip() for x in my_list]
```

Expected list after processing i want to check before '[MY_VARIABLE]':

```
adresse = ['90 rue d’Arras', '76 impasse Georges Pompidou',
'2 allée des fleurs', '90 rue Voltaire']
```

Thanks you for helping me

Comment: if the format of the addresses in your `my_list` is similar, then why don't you just split over `, ` and then take the second element of the returned list?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Because i want only the word matched with "Lille" for this exemple and i don't want "Toulouse".

Comment: Then why in your expected list `address` you have also `'2 allée des fleurs', '90 rue Voltaire'` if you only wanted to match `Lille` ?

Comment: I need to match "Lille" for get after ',' and i don't want get after ',' for "Toulouse" for this example

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور i want to delete all other except ['90 rue d'arras', '76 impasse Georges', '2 allé des fleurs', '90 rue Voltaire']

Answer (score 0):

This looks inelegant to me. What you are really interested in is stripping everything up and including the number. So how about something like this.

```
for s in my_List:
    result = re.match(r".*\d+\w(.*)", s)
    print result.group(1)
```

which gives you, via the (1), the matched group in the (.*).

Comment: yes sorry mistake, but anyway i want trash the number, but for this exemple group i can't use it alway i have AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'